# Error 23 error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char [128]' to 'char (&&)[128]'

Tags: c++

Basically, I wrote the signature of a method that returns a `vector of char` and I am getting this error

```
Error   23  error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'char [128]' to 'char (&&)[128]'
```

Here is the signature of the method

```
vector<char[256]>returnMessage(string ACK)
{
}
```

**Also**, I can't declare a vector of char as a global variable.

When I do this:

```
std::vector<char[256]> myvector;
```

I get:

```
Error   24  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

and

```
Error   23  error C2075: 'Target of operator new()' : array initialization needs curly braces
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with instantiation, but not declaring type. Just use:

```
struct Chars256 {
    char arr[256];
};
```

And you will be able to:

```
vector<Chars256> returnMessage(string ACK) {
    Chars256 arr;
    Chars256 arr2 = {{0}}; // setting value only for first element, all other will be zeros!

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Or `vector<array<char, 256>>`

Answer (score 0):

You receive such errors because of internal code of vector. Template substitution fails.

First error is connected to move semantics. Vector tries to move `char[256]` and fails.

Second with `new` means that somewhere in code of vector there is `new T()` and when `T` is plain array type substitution fails again.

Solution is to use `char*`